# mongodb match in aggregate is not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following 2 schemas:

```
bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'Name required']
               },
        
          author:{
            type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Author'
         
    }

 authorSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
             trim: true,
    
          })
```

I have an array of Author object references and I need to filter books  based on these:

```
authors: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("6358edf901dbe13bc738b63b"),
      name: 'Name 2',
     
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("63592660ca309b7c1a94fb04"),
      name: 'Name 1',
     
      __v: 0
    }
  ]
```

I have tried with below code but it gives empty array as result:

```
Book.aggregate([ { $match: { $expr: { $in: ['Author', authors] } } } ,])
```

Comment: What is the value of `authors` variable?

Comment: authors is the array of the 2 Author  objects defined above. @YongShun

Comment: Does this work? `Book.aggregate([ { $match: {"author": {"$in": authors.map(x => x._id)}}}])`

Comment: Yes it works @rickhg12hs. Can you explain a little bit please? I already tried with Book.aggregate([ { $match: {"author": {"$in": authors._id}}}]) but did not work

Comment: I'm a javascript novice so my explanation probably won't be completely correct.  What I do know is that the argument for MongoDB's `"$in"` should be an array.  `authors` is an array of objects and we only want `_id`.  `authors.map(...` will create an array with the same number of elements as `authors` and `x => x._id` means that for each object element of `authors`, only extract the value of `_id` from each one.  Given my lack of javascript knowledge, it wouldn't surprise me if there's a better way to do it - it's just a way I know.  I tested on [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/jg1yw3qt/).